# Is there a determinant that in the limit becomes the Riemann zeta function?

Tags: matrices, number-theory, riemann-zeta, matrix-calculus

Let the matrix A be:
$$A(n,k): \text{If }  n=k \; \text{ then } 1+\frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{4} (3+2 i t)} k^{\frac{1}{4} (3+2 i t)}}\text{ else }\frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{4} (3+2 i t)} k^{\frac{1}{4} (3+2 i t)}}$$

which is equivalent to:
$$A(n,k): \text{If }  n=k \; \text{ then } 1+\frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{2} (3+2 i t)}}\text{ else }\frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{4} (3+2 i t)} k^{\frac{1}{4} (3+2 i t)}}$$

which is equivalent to  $A=M+I$ where $M$ equals:

$M(n,k)=\frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{4} (3+2 i t)} k^{\frac{1}{4} (3+2 i t)}}$

and $I$ is the identity matrix in linear algebra:

$$I(n,k): \text{If }  n=k \; \text{ then } 1 \text{ else } 0$$

The first few determinants starting at the upper left corner of the infinite matrix $A$ are:

The $1$x$1$ matrix:
$$2$$
The $2$x$2$ matrix:
$$2^{1+\frac{1}{2} (-3-2 i t)}-2^{\frac{1}{2} (-3-2 i t)}+2$$
The $3$x$3$ matrix:
$$2^{1+\frac{1}{2} (-3-2 i t)}-2^{\frac{1}{2} (-3-2 i t)}+3^{\frac{1}{2} (-3-2 i t)}+2$$
...

The plot of the determinant of the $10$ x $10$ matrix looks like this:

[image: determinant]

where the vertical lines are at the Riemann zeta zeros on the critical line.

Compare this to the actual Riemann zeta function on the critical line:
[image]

> Is there a infinite sized matrix, which is not totally degenerate, such that the
>   determinant is the Riemann zeta function?

Associated Mathematica program:

```
(*start*)
Clear[n, k, nn, t, x];
nn = 10;
A = Table[
   Table[If[n == k, 1 + 1/n^(1/4 (3 + 2 I t))/k^(1/4 (3 + 2 I t)), 
     1/n^(1/4 (3 + 2 I t))/k^(1/4 (3 + 2 I t))], {k, 1, nn}], {n, 1, 
    nn}];
pol = Det[A];
Show[Plot[Re[pol], {t, 0, 60}],
 Graphics[
  Table[Line[{{Im[ZetaZero[n]], -30}, {Im[ZetaZero[n]], 30}}], {n, 1, 
    12}]], ImageSize -> Large]
Plot[Re[Zeta[1/2 + I*t]], {t, 0, 60}, ImageSize -> Large]
(*end*)
```

Comment: Your definition of $\;A(n,k)\;$ is, imo, highly confusing: if $\;n=k\;$ , then it seems to be $\;a_{n,n}=1+\cfrac1{n^{\frac12(3+2it)}}\;$ ...but then why to keep the $\;n,\,k\;$ separatedly if they're they the same?

Comment: Reading your title I'd say this question  is the holy grail of mathematics $\>\ldots$

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1980328/8530

Comment: @ChristianBlatter not really. Construct two matrices $A,B$ such that $(AB)_{1,1} = \sum_{n < N} n^{-s}, (AB)_{k,k} = 1$ and $AB$ upper triangular. Then $ \det(AB) = \sum_{n < N} n^{-s}$. And note how this is the same idea as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redheffer_matrix

Comment: What is the definition of the determinant of a matrix of infinite size? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1886/infinite-matrices

Comment: @Did here it works fine as the limit of the sequence of determinant

Comment: @user1952009 What "works fine"? Even if some subdeterminants have a limit, what is the meaning of this limit and is it intrinsic in any way?

Comment: @Did The sequence converges absolutely, so the limit doesn't depend on a permutation of the basis. Now under a unitary change of basis, I don't know.   And I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @user1952009 Sorry but which sequence converges absolutely, to begin with? "Change of basis": this seems offtopic here. "Intrinsic": consider an increasing sequence $(S_n)$ of finite subsets of $\mathbb N$ such that $\bigcup S_n=\mathbb N$, and $D_n$ the determinant restricted to the lines and columns indexed by $S_n$, then is $(D_n)$ converging and is its limit independent of the choice of $(S_n)$?

Comment: @Did did you read my answer below ? You'll have the answer (the OP said $s=\frac14(3+2it)$ but any $Re(s) > 1/2$ will be fine) : the limit is $1+\zeta(2s)$ whatever sequence $S_n\subset S_{n+1}$ you choose

Comment: @user1952009 Right, your trick (posted after my first comment) solves the definition problem.

Comment: @Did: I've looked into the given wikipedia-links on the problem of determinants of infinite-sized matrices. I've one doubt: if the infinite matrix has a LDU-decomposition where the entries of the diagonalmatrix D converge to 1 and if their product  (the sum of their logarithm) converges - wouldn't this allow the notion of a generalized determinant? (The entries of D have a relatively simple analytical formula expressible in a form like $(1+a_n)$ with convergent sequence $a_n$)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Maybe, maybe not. How is knowing the LDU decomposition of the infinite matrix sufficient to know the LDU decomposition of every finite minor?

Comment: @Did - well, now that's going offroad. I've never seen the problem of "every finite minor" before, and this is not really my expertise - so we better leave this idea away at this place...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Just taking the notion of *limit* seriously, don't worry...

Comment: Mats - noticing that there are close-requests: my intuition is, that the core problem in your question is that of the possibility of finding arguments for the generalizability of the "determinant"-term from finite to infinite matrices of a certain type. The involving and the argumentative focus of the zeros-of-the-zeta-aspect seems a bit obfuscative for this attempt and this ambiguity is possibly the source for the "close"-requests. If I met your intention correctly then rewording/reducing your question would likely help to avoid closing and would improve that whole subject. What do you think?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms If you want to edit the question it is fine with me. I had forgotten that I had entered the matrix in my answer in the oeis a few years ago. The analytic continuation should be taken into account. My motivation for asking this question was that if you could define a determinant that is symmetric then maybe you could say something about the Hilbert-Polya conjecture. But I once proved to myself that eigenvalues cannot be arbitrary, and thereby include the zeta zeros. The *symmetry* of a possible determinant is my main hope here.

Comment: Should have read: "But I once proved to myself that eigenvalues cannot be arbitrary, and thereby cannot include the zeta zeros."

Answer (score 1):

I construct the matrix, for instance size 4x4, symbolically, giving the entries at r'th row and c'th column symbolical names which we shall later expand into the actual formulae:
$$ A_4= \small \begin{bmatrix} 
 c_1 r_1+1 & c_2 r_1 & c_3 r_1 & c_4 r_1 \\ 
 r_2 c_1 & c_2 r_2+1 & c_3 r_2 & c_4 r_2 \\ 
 r_3 c_1 & c_2 r_3 & c_3 r_3+1 & c_4 r_3 \\ 
 r_4 c_1 & c_2 r_4 & c_3 r_4 & c_4 r_4+1
 \end{bmatrix} \tag 1
$$
The determinant of this matrix is
$$ det(A_4) = 1+ c_1 r_1 + c_2 r_2 +  c_3 r_3 + c_4 r_4 \tag 2$$
So this is a very simple expression and comparing with larger matrix-sizes we find the obvious generalization.
Now we replace the symbolic names by the actually intended terms 
$$r_k=c_k = k^{-1/4(3+2it)}$$
and have the determinant
$$ \det(A_4) =1+ 1 \cdot 1 + 2^{{-1/4(3+2it)}} \cdot 2^{-1/4(3+2it)} +  3^{{-1/4(3+2it)}} \cdot 3^{-1/4(3+2it)} + 4^{{-1/4(3+2it)}} \cdot 4^{-1/4(3+2it)} \\
=2  + 2^{-1/2(3+2it)} +  3^{-1/2(3+2it)} + 4^{-1/2(3+2it)}
$$ 
The function to plot, in additional dependance of the matrixsize $n$ is the real part of
$$f_n(t) = 2 + \sum_{k=2}^n  {1\over k^{ \, 3/2 + \, î \, t}} \tag 3$$
which is simply the partial-sum evaluation of the zeta at $s=3/2+ î t$  and can thus be written without all the matrix-overhead.

I wouldn't see, why the determinant-expression (2) should not be extended formally to infinite matrices as long it designs a convergent sum, or an expression which could be analytically continued for the infinite-size case.

*(Remark: I do not yet understand why we have the real part of the exponent being 3/2 instead of 1/2, is this perhaps a typo in the question?)*

Answer (score 1):

Fix $N,s$. Your $N \times N$ matrix is $A = I+u^Tu$

where $u = (1,2^{-s},3^{-s},\ldots,N^{-s})$ is a row vector.

Hence thanks to  the [determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma)  $$\det(A) = (1+u u^T)\det(I) = 1+\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-2s}$$

and [Sherman-Morrison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) gives $B = A^{-1} = I - \frac{ u^Tu}{1+uu^T}$ i.e. $B(n,k)= 1_{n=k}-\frac{(nk)^{-s}}{\det(A)}$

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica:

```
Table[M = 
  Table[Table[
    If[Mod[n, k] == 0, MoebiusMu[n/k]/(n/k)^s, If[n == 1, 1, 0]], {k, 
     1, nn}], {n, 1, nn}];
 Expand[FullSimplify[Det[M]]], {nn, 1, 12}]
```

Output:

{1, 1 + 2^-s, 1 + 2^-s + 3^-s, 1 + 2^-s + 3^-s + 4^-s, 
 1 + 2^-s + 3^-s + 4^-s + 5^-s, 1 + 2^-s + 3^-s + 4^-s + 5^-s + 6^-s, 
 1 + 2^-s + 3^-s + 4^-s + 5^-s + 6^-s + 7^-s, 
 1 + 2^-s + 3^-s + 4^-s + 5^-s + 6^-s + 7^-s + 8^-s, 
 1 + 2^-s + 3^-s + 4^-s + 5^-s + 6^-s + 7^-s + 8^-s + 9^-s, 
 1 + 2^-s + 3^-s + 4^-s + 5^-s + 6^-s + 7^-s + 8^-s + 9^-s + 10^-s, 
 1 + 2^-s + 3^-s + 4^-s + 5^-s + 6^-s + 7^-s + 8^-s + 9^-s + 10^-s + 
  11^-s, 1 + 2^-s + 3^-s + 4^-s + 5^-s + 6^-s + 7^-s + 8^-s + 9^-s + 
  10^-s + 11^-s + 12^-s}

https://oeis.org/A143142

Comment: So that whole complicated construction reduces simply to the n'th partial sum of the zeta like $d(n,s) = sum(k=1,n,k^{-s}) $ ? Of course one would expect that this approximates the zeta function and its evaluations/plot over the imaginary part of the exponent should also show the approximations of the zeta zeros. But what is then the real question?

Comment: Again this is a (sequence of) triangular matrix whose determinant is trivial.

Comment: and you should look in details at the $N \times N$ matrix $A_{i,j} = \lfloor \frac{N}{ij} \rfloor$ and at this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/0807.4145.pdf on the $2\sqrt{N}\times 2\sqrt{N}$ matrix $\tilde{A}_{i,j} = \lfloor \frac{N}{s_is_j} \rfloor$